# Matlab plot, remove line from legend

Tags: matlab

I am plotting a point using:

```
color = [0.4660 0.6740 0.1880];
plot(r(1),r(2),'Color',color,'Marker','o','MarkerFaceColor',color,'DisplayName',name);
```

My goal is to have a colored face circle in (x,y) = (`r(1)`,  `r(2)`). This is the resulting image:
[image]

Ignore the straight lines, as they are plotted later on. My legend is then showing as follows:
[image]

How can I remove the line going through the circle in the legend? when trying:

```
plot(r(1),r(2),'go','MarkerFaceColor',color,'DisplayName',name);
```

Everything is good. How can I get a similar legend with my chosen color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this :

```
plot(r(1),r(2),'o','MarkerFaceColor',color,'MarkerEdgeColor', color ,'DisplayName',"receiver");
```

[image]

Comment: This leaves a blue circle around the marker.

Comment: Add  'MarkerEdgeColor'